# Send mail repeat

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have created a workflow in SPD 2010. When item get added it send me email that item has been added which is fine.

But later when I edit item and change field value it again send me mail that item has been added which is not required. Item addition mail should be only once in starting.

Do I need to uncheck "start workflow automatically when workflow is changed"?

But I think this should be checked as based on other column mail need to trigger every time like when status value is changed after every editing each time mail need to send.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have checked "**Start workflow automatically when an item is changed**" check-box in SPD 2010. This is the only reason your workflow is sending email on item changed/update.

Comment: But if i uncheck this , then i wont get mail each time when status field is updated also.

Comment: For that you have to create two workflows, 1 is created for `when item get added`, and create 2nd for `when status field is updated` but this time you have to check the **Start workflow automatically when an item is changed** property for workflow [For 2nd Only].

Comment: I agree with the solution proposed by Rishi.